# Understanding how good is a Pastry-P2P-like resource allocation via DHT

Tags: network-programming, p2p, network-protocols, allocation, distributed-system

I am about to develop a distributed system. The system, among all functionalities, needs to allocate some resources (large resources that can be fragmented in smaller blocks). In order to do that, I want to use the Chord/Pastry P2P approach (stations on a logic ring-net).
Pastry has a very interesting approach for resource allocation: when a user station needs to send something, the hash of the station guid is used to find the key in the dht, so something like this is considered:

User Station -> GUID (hash on user station ip) -> HASH -> I obtain a value called X -> Use this hash and find in the Pastry ring-net the station having that same GUID (hash on Pastry node public key) value is located (or the immediate predecessor) -> put data there.

Well, this means that, ideally, every user always locates its own data in the same Patry station (Pastry node). Well, the protocol also mirrors data on neighbours so a user can find its data in few nodes.

Is this a good approach? Are there any possible side effects on proceeding as before?

Comment: There is no shortage of research comparing DHTs (Pastry, Kademlia, etc...). IMO, it really boils down to what best fits your application.  Simulation may help.

Answer (score 0):

Pastry-P2P-like solution are theoretical models. As such, you should take them for what they are, an abstraction.

These models don't take into account the real practical searching of a peer and the technical difficulties encountered when trying to establish a connection to a remote peer (for example, NAT traversal and firewall issues). A peer can also be down.

The cost of connection to the next peer is not always 1. It can be much more. To answer your question, you cannot only rely on the selected model.

That being said, if the hash results are distributed uniformly, then variation of performance between peers will be low, unless they are particularly hard to reach behind a NAT, a proxy or a firewall.